# What's the significance of the book Bonnie is reading?

Tags: reference, big-little-lies

I'm currently rewatching the second season of HBO's [*Big Little Lies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Little_Lies_(TV_series)). In episode 2.05 titled, *[Kill Me](https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/1651306/big-little-lies-2x05-kill-me)*, Bonnie is reading [*The Wild Trees*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2562408.The_Wild_Trees) by Richard Preston while staying with her mother, who's in the hospital after having a stroke.

***What is the significance of this book in the show?***

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to confirm which book it is (the 2008 paperback version of The Wild Trees by Richard Preston) but I've no idea how the symbolism matches the episode

Comment: Out-of-universe there don't seem to be any obvious connections. A very small number of people worked on this show and Richard Preston's show, The Hot Zone, but none in the set or art departments; https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt4131818,tt3920596. Neither Zoe Kravitz nor Andrea Arnold have worked with Preston before.

Comment: I strongly suspect that whoever was in charge of set dressing just went to the nearest Barnes & Noble and bought whatever was in the rack closest to the checkout.